# Get Claims from STS and AngularJS

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, wif, adfs2.0

I currently use ADFS as a STS and the relying parties are implemented with ASP.NET MVC which are configured with the Identity Access Tool. The relying party is using the .NET WSFederationAuthenticationModule so I can get the claims from the logged in user with

```
((System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal)User).Claims
```

Now I want to switch to angularjs and I ask my self how can this be achieved?
First of all I would like to create the angularjs html page on the server side so I can still use the authentication mechanism from the WSFederationAuthenticationModule.

But I don't know how to get the user claims into my angularjs app in a secure way. An other question I have is, how I can secure webapi calls with the current logged in user. Based on user claims he is allowed to do specific webapi calls.

I read that the angularjs and webapi are using something like secure token exchange.
Has someone done this before or can you give me some advice how to realize this?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try render the Page which contains the hosted AngularJS APP with Asp.NET MVC and try something like this:

```
<script>
    @{var last = ((System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal)User).Claims.Last();}
    var user = {
    @foreach (var claim in ((System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal)User).Claims)
    {
        @claim.Type<text>:</text>@claim.Value if(claim!=last){<text>,</text>} @Environment.NewLine;
    }
    };
</script>
```

This code is only for demonstration. You should cipher the claims. For securing the webapi you can use  web api token authentication with the encrypted claims.

It's not the best solution, but one possible way to realise your  purpose.